# Im trying to cycle through an array an display each item one by one with an interval of one hour

Tags: javascript, arrays

So this is the code that I wrote :

```
var array = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5];
array.forEach(function(obj, num, arr){
function SH(){var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * array.length); setTimeout(array[random].style="opacity:1;transition:0.5;", 3600000 * random);
    setTimeout(  array[random].style="opacity:0; transition:0.5;", 3600000 * random + 1);};
    SH();
    setInterval(SH(), 3600000 * arr.length )
});
```

I want to make a random Image visible for an hour and than stop displaying it and make the next one visible. Im getting the "Cannot set property style of undefined" error. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

`var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * Array.length);` returns undefined.
It's because Array is a keyword in JS. Rename it to `array`

Thanks for the comment. There are actually multiple problems in that code. I wanted to give you the next step how to fix it. There is also an incorrectly defined setTimeout callback and you should also use length - 1

If you'd like a fixed version, here you go:

```
var array = ["image1", "image2", "image3"];
array.forEach(function (obj, num, arr) {
  function SH() {
    var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * array.length - 1);

    setTimeout(() => {
      array[random].style = "opacity:1;transition:0.5;";
    }, 3600000 * random);

    setTimeout(() => {
      array[random].style = "opacity:0; transition:0.5;";
    }, 3600000 * random + 1);
  }
  SH();
  setInterval(SH(), 3600000 * array.length );
});
```

After comments:

```
var array = ["image1", "image2", "image3"];

function SH() {
  var random = Math.ceil(Math.random() * array.length - 1);

  array.forEach(function (obj, num, arr) {
    // if any other index than randomised one
    if (num !== random) {
      array[random].style = "opacity:1;transition:0.5;";
    } else {
      array[num].style = "opacity:0; transition:0";
    }
  });
}

SH(); // start first
setInterval(() => SH(), 3600000); // set the interval
```

Comment: use Math.floor instead as .ceil might return 5 which is out f bound

Comment: @Adam ty for the reply, it doesnt throw an error now, but i guess what happens is it just shows the images and sets the opacity back to zero instantly with no delay or timeout. So basically when i load the page i dont see any images. Do u know how to fix it?

Comment: When I deal with complex code logic I usually read out loud what it does. In your case, you have set interval which delays first execution by `3600000` and after that you delay more by set timeout. From your description I am guessing that you don't actually want the setTimeout at all (delete it) and setInterval is all you need. Still - set interval doesn't execute the function straight away, but starts AFTER the first interval. I updated the comment with another snippet.